# Flutter: How to make camera scan QR Code and capture any image at the same time?

Tags: flutter, image, camera

If the camera detects a QR Code create a callback and if there is none, I should still be able to take a picture of what the camera is seeing, is there a package for this functionality? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For scan a QR Code you can use this library in pub dev

https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner